# Omniture Tracking equal character "=" escape

Tags: javascript, tracking, adobe-analytics

When i use equal character "=" in s.events parameter it not appear in the omniture click event.

example: s.events = "event54=any_string";

Reagrds,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comment on @MisterPhilips's answer:

> Hello, No, I'm not trying to do event serialization, I'm trying to
>   pass in the event click for exampel s.events = "event1=<>". I can do that with a load event (when calling s.tl()) but
>   not with click event (when calling s.th(this, 'o', title))

A "load" event is `s.t()`.  A "click" event is `s.tl()`.  There is no (official) `s.th()` call for Adobe Analytics (AA).

The reason why it "works" for a load event is because the AA code doesn't require you to "register" events on an `s.t()` call.  However, events and variables must be "registered" for `s.tl()` calls, or they won't show up in the request.

You "register" events with `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents`, like this (example):

```
s.linkTrackEvents="event54";
s.linkTrackVars="events";
s.events="event54=<something>";
// example click call
s.tl(true,'o','some click');
```

Having said that, @MisterPhilip is right about what values you can set to an event.  The only type of events AA has are numeric/counter/currency - all a *number* type.  That is because events are meant to be used as metrics in reports, not dimensions.

So, while you *can* do the above code, and it *will* be sent in the AA request, AA server is going to look at that and toss it out because it's an invalid value.

If you want to set something to an arbitrary (string) value, you need to make use of the dimension type variables, most commonly `props` or `eVars`, but there are others like `hier` or `list`, as well.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is a reserved character, used for setting the value for a numeric or currency event.

```
s.events = "event1=51.23,event2=3";
```

Are you trying to do [event serialization](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/event_serialization.html) instead?

Comment: Hello,
No, I'm not trying to do event serialization, I'm trying to pass in the event click for exampel s.events = "event1=<<any string>>". I can do that with a load event (when calling s.tl()) but not with click event (when calling s.th(this, 'o', title))